# Is it possible to install bundler using bundler --standalone

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I know this may sound weird - maybe like search for "google" using google - but I'm fighting with a problem using the standalone feature of bundler.

Background:

I'm creating a rpm for "single click" installation of a rails application. What I don't want is to build all the necessary gems on the target server - I want to deliver them within the rpm file.

So I did the "hack" using

```
bundle install --standalone default --binstubs bin/
```

But rails require bundler. Shure there are ways to remove bundler from rails - but this isn't easy in an grown application. So I don't have a problem with using bundler in my production setup.

But bundler won't install bundler to the standalone folder - and I couldn't figure out how to do this

Is there a way to work arround this? Or is there a better way without building the gems locally and without refactoring the rails app?